# What to do about Corporate ownership and registration renewal documents if Delaware corporate state registry had expired?

Tags: corporate-law

20 years ago a corporation was formed to purchase a private aircraft.  The Delaware corporation's state charter had expired years ago due to non-payment of renewal fee.  What are the legal consequences for aircraft renewal documents filed with the FAA or other authorities if the underlying corporate entity legally no longer exists?

Answer (score 1):

### [Revive](https://corp.delaware.gov/renew09/) the company

Delaware (and most other) jurisdictions allow the revival of an administratively deregistered company on payment of back-taxes and fees.